# AngularJS Remove blank rows

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a practice project with angularjs, i thought i have completed it when a strange bug appears and i am not able to solve it. To understand the bug please go to this heroku app : https://stormy-refuge-89690.herokuapp.com

1. Check Mark 2015
2. Click on input search field under "Search By Team 1" then type "everton".
3. Now you can see everything is getting filtered correctly. Now Delete "everton" from this input field.
4. Type "everton" in input filed under "Search By Team 2".
5. You will see some blank rows.

Those blank rows are the problem that should not appear according to code logic i have used in all-controller.js :

```
vm.checkTeams = function(matches, teamSearch, team1Search, team2Search){
    var found = false;
    if(teamSearch != undefined){
        found = true;
    }
    if(team1Search != undefined){
        matches.forEach(function(data){
            var team1 = data.team1.name.toLowerCase();
            if(team1.search(team1Search) != -1){
                found = true;
            }
        });
    }
    if(team2Search != undefined){
        matches.forEach(function(data){
            var team2 = data.team2.name.toLowerCase();
            if(team2.search(team2Search) != -1){
                found = true;
            }
        });
    }
    if(found == true)
        return true;
    if(teamSearch == undefined && team1Search == undefined && team2Search == undefined)
        return true;
}
```

View html-angular template which is served using routes :

```
<div class="col-12">
  <h3 class="mypara pt-3">Please Checkmark one of the Years :</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
      <h3>2015<input type="checkbox" class="check ml-2" ng-model="isChecked2015"></h3></div>
      <div class="col-4"><h3>2016<input type="checkbox" class="check ml-2" ng-model="isChecked2016"></h3></div>
      <div class="col-4"><h3>2017<input type="checkbox" class="check ml-2" ng-model="isChecked2017"></h3></div>
      <div class="col-4 pb-5 pt-5">
          <label for="search">Search By Team</label>
          <input ng-model="teamSearch" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Team/Date">        
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 pb-5 pt-5">
          <label for="search">Search By Team1</label>
          <input ng-model="team1Search.team1.name" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Team1">        
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 pb-5 pt-5">
          <label for="search">Search By Team2</label>
          <input ng-model="team2Search.team2.name" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Team2">        
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display:none;" ng-if="isChecked2015==true && isChecked2016!=true && isChecked2017!=true">
  <div ng-init="vm.year = 2015; vm.loop = vm.data2015;"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" ng-if="isChecked2016==true && isChecked2015!=true && isChecked2017!=true">
    <div ng-init="vm.year = 2016; vm.loop = vm.data2016;"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" ng-if="isChecked2017==true && isChecked2016!=true && isChecked2015!=true">
  <div ng-init="vm.year = 2017; vm.loop = vm.data2017;"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" ng-if="isChecked2015==true && isChecked2016==true && isChecked2017!=true">
  <div ng-init="vm.year = [2015, 2016]; vm.loop = vm.data2015.concat(vm.data2016);"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" ng-if="isChecked2015!=true && isChecked2016==true && isChecked2017==true">
  <div ng-init="vm.year = [2016, 2017]; vm.loop = vm.data2016.concat(vm.data2017);"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" ng-if="isChecked2015==true && isChecked2016!=true && isChecked2017==true">
  <div ng-init="vm.year = [2015, 2017]; vm.loop = vm.data2015.concat(vm.data2017);"></div>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" ng-if="isChecked2015==true && isChecked2016==true && isChecked2017==true || isChecked2015!=true && isChecked2016!=true && isChecked2017!=true">
  <div ng-init="vm.year = [2015, 2016, 2017]; vm.loop = vm.totaldata;"></div>
</div>
<h3 class="mypara">Displaying for Year : {{vm.year}}</h3>
<div class="table-responsive" ng-repeat="data in vm.loop | filter: teamSearch" class="col-12 text-center" ng-show="isChecked2015 || isChecked2016 || isChecked2017 || isChecked2015!=true && isChecked2016!=true && isChecked2017!=true">    
    <table class="table table-sm table-dark opac" ng-if="vm.eachDateCheck(data.matches, vm.year) && vm.checkTeams(data.matches, teamSearch, team1Search.team1.name, team2Search.team2.name)">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="p-3">Date</th>
        <th scope="col" class="p-3">Team1</th>
        <th scope="col" class="p-3">Score</th>
        <th scope="col" class="p-3">Team2</th>
        <th scope="col" class="p-3">Winner Team</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <div ng-if="vm.eachDateCheck(data.matches, vm.year) && vm.checkTeams(data.matches, teamSearch, team1Search.team1.name, team2Search.team2.name)"><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><h3>{{data.name}}</h3></div>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="matchday in data.matches | filter:teamSearch | filter:team1Search | filter:team2Search" ng-if="vm.rowDateCheck(matchday.date.slice(0,4), vm.year)">
          <td class="p-3">{{matchday.date}}</td>
          <td class="p-3">{{matchday.team1.name;}}</td>
          <td class="p-3"><span ng-class="{won: matchday.score1 > matchday.score2, lost:matchday.score1 < matchday.score2, equal:matchday.score2 == matchday.score1}">{{matchday.score1}}</span><span class="vs">VS</span><span ng-class="{won: matchday.score2 > matchday.score1, lost:matchday.score2 < matchday.score1, equal:matchday.score2 == matchday.score1}">{{matchday.score2}}</span></td>
          <td class="p-3">{{matchday.team2.name}}</td>
          <td class="p-3" ng-show="matchday.score1 > matchday.score2">{{matchday.team1.name}}</td>
          <td class="p-3" ng-show="matchday.score2 > matchday.score1">{{matchday.team2.name}}</td>
          <td class="p-3" ng-show="matchday.score1 == matchday.score2">Draw</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </div>
    </table>
</div>
```

According to the logic used in this line :

```
<table class="table table-sm table-dark opac" ng-if="vm.eachDateCheck(data.matches, vm.year) && vm.checkTeams(data.matches, teamSearch, team1Search.team1.name, team2Search.team2.name)">
```

It will check if year and team names are present in the table rows or not, if present it wil return true and if not present in will return false, although everything is correct in the code then why those blank table rows are appearing? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code in the post.

Comment: My bad, I have included the relevant parts of code. Thanks

Comment: @Farhan Your code works fine, since team two, checks if the opposing team contains "Everton", since "Match Day 2" and "Match Day 4" contain values they are populated, while "Match Day 1" and "Match Day 3" do not contain everton in the opposing teams, so we seeing no rows. Please highlight what is the issue in more detail!

Comment: @NarenMurali I have stated the problem clearly, "Those blank rows are the problem that should not appear according to code logic i have used", the function vm.checkTeams() will return false and the table will be hidden because of ng-if condition, but those blank tables are not getting hide, that's the problem,  any clue why it is happening ?